# attribute error: none type object has no shape

Tags: python, c++, opencv, numpy, computer-vision

I can't run this script successfully.
I have tried running it via command line whilst passing arguments and without. I have also tried to run in a virtualenv to no avail. I suspect I am missing a driver for PiCamera to work

```
# if a video path was not supplied, grab the reference
# to the webcam
if not args.get("video", False):
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# otherwise, grab a reference to the video file
else:
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])

# keep looping
while True:
    # grab the current frame
    (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/ball-tracking/ball_tracking.py", line 48, in <module>
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imutils/convenience.py"`enter code here`, line 45, in resize
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: whats wrong with it?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/ball-tracking/ball_tracking.py", line 48, in <module>
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imutils/convenience.py"`enter code here`, line 45, in resize
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'nonetype' object referred to the frame that was not passed to the resize method.

This is solved by loading the pre-installed v4l2 drivers before running the code as such:

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```